# Using xarray where() to create a mask from a netCDF file

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

Ive spent all day on this and am still stuck. Im trying to write a function that takes a netCDF file (which has NaNs or a specific value in it) and masks another netCDF file (that is mostly full, but has some NaNs where there is no data). Its geographic data, so im trying to mask a region. So the result i expect is a map with only the region of interest shown, but what i get is a the full data of the file i tried to mask, as if the masking did nothing. I dont get any errors when executing the code. Here is what I have tried:

- ive check the directories of all the files in the function; they exist, and i have read and write permission (i am using a local network and my machine)
- generally toyed around with what variable i am selecting etc

```
def mask_data(ifile, mask_folder,data_masked):
# data_masked = '/file/path/to/save/outout/'
# ifile = netcdf file
# mask_folder = folder with various netcdf files, all of which are independent masks and loop over the ifile, to generate different maps with different selected regions
    ds = xr.open_dataset(ifile, engine='netcdf4')
    
    for mask_file in os.listdir(mask_folder):
        mask_path = os.path.join(mask_folder, mask_file)
        output_file = masked+'masked_data'+mask_file+'.nc'
        ds_mask = xr.open_dataset(mask_path)

        # apply the mask to the ifile data
        ds_masked = ds['var'].where(ds_mask)

        ds_ghf_masked.to_netcdf(output_file)

        ds_mask.close() # remember to close the opened datasets!!
        
    ds_ghf.close()
    return
```

i am at a complete loss as to why, when i call mask_data(), i simply get the ifile saved in the directory masked_data 20 times (the amount of seperate mask files i have). I thought maybe they are layering on top of one another, but that would imply only the last file would be the full ifile, but all of them are. Help, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues in your code that are causing problems.

- First I'm not sure based on your post what values in `ds_mask` represent the values you want to keep. Is it where the mask equals 1? or where the mask is not NaN?
- Second, the variable you are saving out with `.to_netcdf()` is not the one you just created with the masking. The variable you created is `ds_masked` and the one you are saving out is `ds_ghf_masked` so that will be why the saved netcdf files are all the same.
- Assuming you want to keep data where the mask equals 1 and drop the rest, and assuming that the name of the variable in `ds_mask` is `mask`, you want to do:

```
def mask_data(ifile, mask_folder,data_masked):
# data_masked = '/file/path/to/save/outout/'
# ifile = netcdf file
# mask_folder = folder with various netcdf files, all of which are independent masks and loop over the ifile, to generate different maps with different selected regions
    ds = xr.open_dataset(ifile, engine='netcdf4')
    
    for mask_file in os.listdir(mask_folder):
        mask_path = os.path.join(mask_folder, mask_file)
        output_file = masked+'masked_data'+mask_file+'.nc'
        ds_mask = xr.open_dataset(mask_path)

        # apply the mask to the ifile data
        # this will give a DataArray as output
        da_masked = ds['var'].where(ds_mask['mask']==1, drop=True)

        # Convert the DataArray to a Dataset for saving
        ds_masked = da_masked.to_dataset()

        # Save Dataset out to netcdf
        ds_masked.to_netcdf(output_file)

    return
```

To explain, `xr.Dataset.where(cond)` keeps the data where `cond` is True. Then if `drop=False` (the default), it sets the values where `cond` is False to NaN, or if `drop=True`, it gets rid of the values where `cond` is False. Hope that helps!

Comment: ah thank you so much! by going through your answer carefully, i found where i went wrong and it now creates a proper mask of my data:) to answer your questions about the original code, the ds_mask is actually both - the values I want to keep are 1, and the rest are NaN. So the solution you gave for this part worked well. Also, d'oh on my part for not properly calling the thing I wanted to save! Thats what a whole day at a screen does to your eyes i guess

Comment: Also, i have a question about the dataarray vs dataset thing, this also helped me a created the mask i wanted. So in general, using ```xr.where()``` will always return a data array and not dataset, right? and we cant convert a data array to a netcdf file with ```.to_netcdf()```, have have to make it a dataset first?

Comment: Glad to help. To answer your other questions, `xr.where()` can return a Dataset if you give it a Dataset as input. I just generally prefer a DataArray as a Dataset can contain many variables of many different shapes and so you generally don't want to act on all of them at once. And yes, you need to convert to a dataset before calling `to_netcdf()`. You can call `to_netcdf()` directly on a DataArray, but it will be automatically converted to a Dataset before saving.